# How to get pause/stop sound from Webview when press back home screen ?

Tags: javascript, android, audio, webview

When I press home screen button, I want to pause or stop sound in webview and when I go back in webview sound will play again. But now it is still playing and media player in android is NULL because all of content including sound work from Javascript and thats my leader told me ***"DONT edit or do anything in Javascript. edit or do only in android"***, so I can not pause or stop it. this is my problem.

Answer (score 2):

when you press home button current activity goes in onpause() state and when you again revisit your application and open that activity it call onResume method

so i suggest you to override onpause() and onResume() methods and put your code for sound pause yaa stop in onpause() and play again sound by placing code in onResume() method

for more about activity life cycle refer this :
[Link1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

> You can call through to the WebView's `onPause()` and `onResume()` from
>   your Activity's `onPause()` and `onResume()`, respectively.

Comment: thank you for answer but it does not work and its nothing happens.

Comment: it still playing on background screen.. this my code

protected void onPause() {
  Log.v(SharedVariable.LOG_TAG, "WEBVIEW : onBackPress Pause1111");
  super.onPause();
  _webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  Log.v(SharedVariable.LOG_TAG, "WEBVIEW : onBackPressed" + " ==>543210 " + _webView.getOriginalUrl());
// if (!isFirstTimeLoad) {
// _webView.goBack();
 _webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  
   // _webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//  }

}

Comment: can u plz paste on pastie.org